# Freeze first row of Google spreadsheet when displayed in Google site

Tags: google-sheets, google-classic-sites

When a Google spreadsheet is displayed in a Google site window, the complete table being displayed moves when the displayed window is scrolled. The top row containing headers moves out of view. This makes it very difficult to understand which column contains what information.

How do I freeze the first row of a Google spreadsheet when displayed in a Google site?

Answer (score 1):

View -> Freeze Rows -> Freeze **1 row**

That should keep the first row of your document always visible while scrolling.

Comment: Thanks! I have done the method you told. But still when google-spreadsheet is opened in google-site the freeze command has no effect. First row also moves out of view on scrolling.

Comment: How exactly have you displayed the Sheets file in your Site?